# Antivirus significantly slowing down writing to disk, is there a workaround that prevents storing data in memory?

Tags: c#

Let's say I'm receiving a file over a socket stream, I am receiving 1024 bytes at a time. Each time I write to the harddisk, my antivirus scans the entire file. The bigger the file gets, the longer it takes to write the next 1024 bytes. Not to mention the "file is in use by another process" errors.

My workaround at the moment is to just store the bytes in a byte array in the memory, up to X megabytes (user defined), the byte array is appended to the file on the harddisk every time it fills up.

```
byte[] filebytearray = new byte[filesize]; //Store entire file in this byte array.

do
{
    serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
    bytesRead = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize); //How many bytes did we just read from the stream?
    recstrbytes = new byte[bytesRead]; //Final byte array this loop
    Array.Copy(inStream, recstrbytes, bytesRead); //Copy from inStream to the final byte array this loop
    Array.Copy(recstrbytes, 0, filebytearray, received, bytesRead); //Copy the data from the final byte array this loop to filebytearray

    received += recstrbytes.Length; //Increment bytes received

}while (received < filesize);

addToBinary(filebytearray, @"C:\test\test.exe"); //Append filebytearray to binary
```

(In this simplified example it just stores the entire file in memory before unloading it to hdd)

But I absolutely hate this method because it significantly increases the memory my program uses.

How do other programmers tackle this issue? When I download with firefox, as an example, it just downloads with full speed, my AV doesn't seem to pick it up until it's done, and it barely increases the process' memory usage. What's the big secret here?

Append to binary function I am using (WIP):

```
private bool addToBinary(byte[] msg, string filepath)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Appending "+msg.Length+" bytes of data.");

    bool succ = false;

    do
    {
        try
        {
            using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                fileStream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                fileStream.Flush();
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            succ = true;
        }
        catch (IOException ex) { /*Console.WriteLine("Write Exception (addToBinary) : " + ex.Message);*/ }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("Some Exception occured (addToBinary) : " + ex.Message); return false; }
    } while (!succ);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Chrome at least doesn't call the target file "text.exe" - it calls it "test.exe.crdownload" until it's done, then it renames it to .exe. Are you actually closing and reopening the file between blocks?? I can't imagine an AV program would scan a partially-written file. Which one is it?

Comment: exe's definitely take longer to scan than other files, but they still take some time.. I was hoping for something better (if it exists). I am using Panda Cloud Antivirus. And you are right, it closes and re- opens the file every block.. maybe that's the issue!

Comment: You can configure some anti-virus programs to ignore files or directories.  In Symantec Endpoint Protection I can do this under Centralized Exceptions.  Maybe something like this would help?

Comment: @Marnee I have no control over the AV settings of people using my program. So unfortunately, no ;)

Comment: @Steve Again, it is not *my* AV I am worried out, it's the AV of the future users of the application(s). I have no control over those.

Comment: Right, it looks like you're closing and re-opening the file to do each append. That's probably what other programs do differently. Why not keep the stream open until you're finished?

Comment: @Rup That definitely helped. It seems that as long as c# has a write lock on the file, the AV can't screw around with it.. could you add this as an answer please?

Comment: @natli - Why do you care if your program uses a user's memory that is what its for?  Furthermore what directory are you saving the file to?

Comment: @Ramhound That doesn't justify using 1GB of memory if the user wants to save some big files, lol. And offloading it every 20mb or so would still mean tons of unnecessary scans by the AV. But the problem is already solved, just waiting for Rup to add the answer because I cant select a comment as an answer :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you reopen the file every time you write data. Why not keep the file stream opened? Every time you close it, the antivirus scans it, because it was modified.

And one suggestion, the WriteLine function works like printf in c++, so... Instead of doing:

```
Console.WriteLine("Appending "+msg.Length+" bytes of data.");
```

you could do:

```
Console.WriteLine("Appending {0} bytes of data.", msg.Length);
```

This could really save your time sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use a memory stream.
Second, you have to write to disk some times, just do it in the background so user won't notice.

Make a concurrent queue of memory stream, and create a handler that will try to empty the queue.

Answer (score 0):

You could add exclusions to your antivirus to stop it interfering. If you want the data to be scanned, then download it to an excluded folder and then move it to a folder (that will be scanned) when the file is complete.

Other approaches would be to buffer the data so you are not writing in tiny 1k increments, and hold the file open until you have finished writing.

Comment: I cannot believe people keep recommending this :P I have no control over the antivirus settings of potential users of my software, meaning this is not a solution. Also your 'other approach' (buffering) is exactly what I wanted to avoid, as I explained. Thanks for taking time to answer, though!

Comment: Then follow my other suggestion and _keep the file open_. Don't blame me if you don't like the only viable solutions, I'm just trying to help you by suggesting possible options that you can pick from.